# Issue with Port Forwarding

Tags: port-forwarding, airport

I am trying to port forward a server of mine but I can't find any tutorials that help with my specific setup. I have Spectrum DOCSIS service connected to an Arris SB6141 connected to an Apple AirPort Extreme. I cant find the right site to do it.

Q: With the setup above how do I enable port forwarding?

Answer (score 1):

Your Arris SB6141 is purely a modem, and doesn't get involved with ports.

Use the AirPort Utility for macOS or iOS to configure port forwarding (may be called "Port Mapping" or "Port Settings") on your AirPort Extreme. The old AirPort Utility for Windows might even still work if you don't have a Mac or iOS device.